# Print a qword stored in eax:ebx x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to make a macro who print a qword(decimal).

```
show_qd macro nr
   lea edx,[nr]
   mov eax,[edx] ;upper 32 bits
   mov ebx,[edx+4] ;lower 32 bits

   ;print code here;

endm
```

Sadly, i can't figure out how to do it with x86 instructions...

Comment: Print out - how? Decimal, hexadecimal, binary? Can you figure out how to print a single byte value in the notational system of your choice?

Comment: If decimal, you can check for one routine here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41086442/4271923 (btw, don't put whole routine into macro, it will repeat it in the machine code for each usage => big binary => slow. Rather use `call` and subroutines.)

Comment: I found a very easy way : 
push ebx ; lower 32 bits
push eax ; upper 32 bits 
push offset format
call printf
add esp,12 ; clear the stack 

where format is 
format DB "%lld", 0

Comment: @Crisan indeed, if you are already linking to clib, then there's little reason to not use one of printf family functions. Although for safety reasons (buffer overflow) I would suggest to use mostly \**n*printf variants, but in case of `"%lld"` you can be assured 21B buffer is enough for all possible values.

Comment: Note that x86 is little-endian, so a quad-word is actually stored in `EDX:EAX`, where `EDX` is the *high* bits (most significant) and `EAX` is the *low* bits (least significant). Your question and sample code have it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no x86 instruction to "print" a value. Displaying output requires an operating-system-specific interface. In "classic" x86 programming, you would make a BIOS call to generate output to the screen. In modern protected-mode operating systems, this will no longer work. Instead, you need to call an OS API function to display the output, *e.g.* to a console window associated with your process.

The easiest and most universal way to call that OS API is to link your assembly program with the C standard library so that you can call its `printf` (and similar) function(s). This requires little more than a `CALL` instruction, which transfers control to the `printf` function, executes it, and returns control to the following instruction in your code.

There is, however, one additional complication: you must follow the appropriate *calling convention* for your platform and for the standard library functions. Your question offers no clues about whether you're using Windows, Linux, or something else. Fortunately, detailed information about x86 calling conventions is available in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info). In general, 32-bit calling conventions will pass parameters on the stack from right-to-left. And the C standard library functions are virtually always caller-cleanup (even on Windows, where a callee-cleanup convention is otherwise common), so you are responsible for cleaning up the stack after making the call.

Thus, just as a demonstration, here is how you might call `printf` to print the 32-bit integer stored in the `EAX` register:

```
push  eax                  ; push 32-bit integer value from EAX onto stack
push  OFFSET strFormat     ; push pointer to format string onto stack
call  printf
add   esp, 8               ; clean up stack
```

`strFormat` must be a string stored in your executable's `DATA` section. The format strings are the same as for C, since it's exactly the same function. In this case, then, it would be pushing a pointer to a string containing `"%d"`.

Things are much the same to print a 64-bit value, except that your format string is `"%lld"` (use the `long long` type in C, which is 64 bits on x86-32). You need to follow the calling convention's rules for passing a 64-bit integer parameter to a function. It is likely that this will simply involve pushing both 32-bit halves onto the stack. Assuming that the 64-bit value is stored canonically in `EDX:EAX`, the code would be as follows:

```
push  edx                    ; push upper 32 bits of 64-bit integer value onto stack
push  eax                    ; push lower 32 bits of 64-bit integer value onto stack
push  OFFSET strFormat64     ; push pointer to format string onto stack
call  printf
add   esp, 12                ; clean up stack
```

If the value is in memory, then you can use code like you show in the question:

```
lea   edx, DWORD PTR [value]
mov   eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
mov   edx, DWORD PTR [edx+4]

push  edx
push  eax
push  OFFSET strFormat64
call  printf

add   esp, 12
```

Note that if you implement this as a macro, it will clobber registers. Make sure either that this is clearly documented, or that you save and restore the registers inside of the macro—otherwise, you'll end up with difficult-to-debug problems when you use this in your code! And, depending on your calling convention, you might need to make sure that the stack is properly aligned, which can be difficult to do cleanly and generically in a macro. MASM has an `INVOKE` pseudo-instruction that can handle calling a function for you automatically. It might be worth checking to see if your assembler of choice has a similar feature.